# Is it possible to check if a connection is local or via ssh *after* elevating to the root account with `sudo`?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, ssh

I want to see if I'm connected via ssh or running a local terminal.

If I just ssh into a server without changing to root via `sudo`, it's easy. Any of the variables `$SSH_CLIENT`, `$SSH_CONNECTION` or `$SSH_TTY` can be used to check if one is connected via SSH or local.

Problem: When I elevate to the root account with `sudo -i` to do administrative stuff, neither of  these variables are helpful - they are all empty.

What is the best way to find out if the connection is local or via SSH then?

EDIT: With the accepted answer, it is easy to have an unobtrusive bash prompt which reflects ssh status and privileges:

```bsh
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    # when system is accessed via SSH, hostname with light grey background
    if [[ $(pstree -s $$) = *sshd* ]]; then sshbg="\[\033[48;5;7m\]"; fi
    # when used as root, change username to orange and '#' to red for prompt
    if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then usercol="\[\033[38;5;3m\]"; hashcol="\[\033[38;5;1m\]"; else usercol="\[\033[38;5;2m\]"; fi
    # bash PS1 prompt
    PS1="${usercol}\u\[$(tput sgr0)\]@\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;4m\]${sshbg}\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]:\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;6m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]${hashcol}\\$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
    unset sshbg rootcol hashcol
fi
```

The timed version of the `pstree` part runs in less than 20ms, so it can be used without introducing noticeable delays.

Comment: Probably this could be interesting for you: [How do I find who is logged-in as root?](https://askubuntu.com/q/980950/566421)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're in a bash shell, you can do `pstree -s $$` ($$ is the current shell's PID) and look for "sshd" in the output.

Comment: Added another idea as an edit, try `pstree -s $$`

Comment: This is actually the best suggestion. Looking for "sshd" in the string

Comment: I researched the implications of your suggestion for a while, and it seems that the `pstree` trick is indeed the best variant. I would like to award you best answer, but at the moment, there's still the `cat` suggestion on top which is misleading and doesn't help much. Could you rewrite your answer a little?

Comment: Nuked the `cat` option :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
who am i | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
```

If it says pts/0, pts/1 etc. you're on SSH, if it says tty1, tty2 etc. you're on a local connection.

When I connect using SSH I get the following from `who am i`:

```
am       pts/0        2020-08-28 12:33 (172.17.0.5)
```

Maybe the IP address can also be used as an indicator to differentiate an SSH connection from a local connection on the desktop.

Also explained here: [How to check which tty am I currently using?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902998/how-to-check-which-tty-am-i-currently-using).

Comment: This appears to not work if you're in a Desktop environment :( `who am i` literally returns nothing.

Comment: For me, `who am i` (or `who -m` really) returns the same value for Desktop environment and SSH session - pts/0. Works for a real tty, though, but only to use from tty is too strong a restriction.

Comment: What about the IP address `who am i` returns as 5th column? What does the IP say when you're in a desktop environment - just the IP of localhost? Maybe you can use this as an indicator.

Comment: It appears to be some weird byproduct of certain versions of gnome-terminal.  I don't know if it's a bug or something reliable.  I found bug ticket for RHEL: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=91442

Comment: Ah ok - yeah it sounds like a bug if it's not consistent at least - because if it were consistent then it would also be a usable criteria to determine the answer to the OP.